# Largest Sum Contiguous Subarray - Kadene's algorithm

Tags: java, interview-questions

I am looking forward to an answer to improve this code?

Thanks.

Test class

```
package test;

import main.algorithms.LargestSumContiguousSubarray;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LargestSumContiguousSubarrayTest {

    LargestSumContiguousSubarray largestSumContiguousSubarray;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        largestSumContiguousSubarray = new LargestSumContiguousSubarray();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSumContiguousSubArray(){
        int[] a = {-2, -3, 4 - 1, -2, 1, 5, -3};
        int sum = 7;
        Assert.assertEquals(sum, largestSumContiguousSubarray.kadenesAlgo(a));
    }

}
```

LargestSumContiguousSubarray.java class

```
package main.algorithms;

public class LargestSumContiguousSubarray {

    // O(n)
    // Kadene's algorithm
    public int kadenesAlgo(int[] a) {

        // This is also works for negative numbers
        int max_so_far = a[0];
        int curr_max = a[0];

        for(int i=0;i<a.length; i++){
            curr_max = Math.max(a[i], curr_max+a[i]);
            max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, curr_max);
        }
        return max_so_far;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I'd improve is to fix Kadane's name.

Comment: This looks like a typo to me... `, 4 - 1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Doi9t 's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/247377/203649) already covered the ways how to improve your code. The first iteration of your for loop will return these assignments:

```
curr_max = a[0]
//inside your loop 
curr_max = Math.max(a[0], curr_max + a[0]);
max_so_far = Math.max(a[0], curr_max);
```

So the first iteration will return a value of `max_so_far` equal to 2 * a[0]  if a[0] >= 0 or a[0] if a[0] < 0 and this is a **bug**, for example your method for  array {1} will return the value 2. I have seen from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) that the algorithm set your variables `max_so_far` and `curr_max` to 0, this would solve the bug of your code.

Answer (score 4):

I have some suggestions for your code.

### Replace the `for` loop with an enhanced 'for' loop

In your code, you don’t actually need the index provided by the loop, you can use the enhanced version.

**before**

```java
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
//[...]
}
```

**after**

```java
for (int current : a) {
//[...]
}
```

### Variable and parameter name should be in camelCase style

The variables should be in camelCase.